# why i am getting error of "cannot read property 'state' of undefined " in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

my store/index.js is :

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex)
export default
new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    name: 'Alicia Vikander',
    age: 20,
    dob: '20/08/1990'
  },
  mutations: {
    updateName(state, name) => {
      state.name = name
    }
  }
})
```

and my component.vue is :

```html
<template>
  <div>
    {{ $store.state.name }}
  </div>
</template>
```

why i am  getting error of

> cannot read property 'state' of undefined

in vue js ?  please help.. thanks in advance

Comment: where are you import store in your project? you should provide created store to root vue component.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you have injected store to the component like this:

```
 let store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
    name: 'Alicia Vikander',
    age: 20,
    dob: '20/08/1990'
  },
  mutations: {
    updateName(state, name) => {
      state.name = name
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

Comment: It must work, check this fiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Herteby/o48jbxhp/)